# Auto-generation of .NET unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, automation, automated-tests

Is there such a thing as unit test generation? If so...

...does it work well?

...What are the auto generation solutions that are available for .NET?

...are there examples of using a technology like this?

...is this only good for certain types of applications, or could it be used to replace all manually written unit testing?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Take a look at [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/Pex/). Its a Microsoft Research project. From the website:

*Pex generates Unit Tests from hand-written Parameterized Unit Tests through Automated Exploratory Testing based on Dynamic Symbolic Execution.*

### UPDATE for 2019:

As mentioned in the comments, Pex is now called [IntelliTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/generate-unit-tests-for-your-code-with-intellitest?view=vs-2019) and is a feature of Visual Studio Enterprise Edition. It supports emitting tests in MSTest, MSTest V2, NUnit, and xUnit format and it is extensible so you can use it with other unit test frameworks.

But be aware of the following caveats:

- Supports only C# code that targets the .NET Framework.
- Does not support x64 configurations.
- Available in Visual Studio **Enterprise Edition only**

Comment: This has been productized as "Intellitest" for at least two releases of VS (2015, 2017). After all this time, it still only works on x86.

Comment: Anyone know where a plugin for xUnit is? xUnit's author has one but it is a 1.0.RC for VS2015. Another plugin out there only does test case creation, but is not compatible with IntelliTest. Any other options?

Answer (score 24):

I believe there's no point in Unit test generation, as far as TDD goes.

You only make unit tests so that you're sure that you (as a developer) are on track w/ regards to design and specs. Once you start generating tests automatically, it loses that purpose. Sure it would probably mean 100% code coverage, but that coverage would be senseless and empty.

Automated unit tests also mean that your strategy is test-after, which is opposite of TDD's test-before tenet. Again, TDD is not about tests.

That being said I believe MSTest does have an automatic unit-test generation tool -- I was able to use one with VS2005.

Comment: Super old comment, but no one's replied and I felt it worth saying: I totally agree, but a lot of people are not in TDD. We want a quick jumpstart on tests for code already written for various reasons. In my case, I have a code base that doesn't have tests. I want to get tests in it before adding more functionality and just want a good head start. So there are reasons for doing this, but starting a project, from scratch, and finishing it and THEN putting in unit tests is a terrible idea, you're right.

Comment: @vbullinger this is especially true for developers who inherit legacy applications.  Yep, they (just) might work but it would be handy to draw a line under the code with a set of tests then moving forwards, fixes introduced can be added to the tests already generated.

Comment: "Does Pex completely replace hand written Unit Tests? The short answer is No." http://buff.ly/1oy1vyn

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use autogenerated unit tests for regression testing before refactoring or introducing potentially breaking changes.

Comment: Just getting some boilerplate code that has a [Fact] for each public method of a class would be a very helpful starting point for writing the actual tests myself.

Answer (score 21):

Updated for 2017:

[Unit Test Boilerplate Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RandomEngy.UnitTestBoilerplateGenerator) works for VS 2015-2017 and is being maintained. Seems to work as advertised.

Comment: 2023 checking in. It's still being maintained, while the original fork from Microsoft has been archived. Working great for me in VS 2022 64-bit. Has a few quirks with saving and loading your workspace settings, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

[Parasoft .TEST](http://www.parasoft.com) has a functionality of tests generation. It uses NUnit framework for tests description and assertions evaluation.

It is possible to prepare a regression tests suite by automated generating scenarios (constructing inputs and calling tested method) and creating assertions which are based on the current code base behavior. Later, after code base under tests evolves, assertions indicates regressions or can be easily recorded again.

Answer (score 2):

I created `ErrorUnit`. It generates `MSTest` or `NUnit` unit tests from your paused `Visual Studio` or your error logs; Mocking class variables, Method Parameters, and EF Data access so far. See http://ErrorUnit.com

No Unit Test generator can do everything. Unit Tests are classically separated into three parts *Arrange*, *Act*, and *Assert*; the Arrange portion is the largest part of a unit test, and it sets up all the preconditions to a test, mocking all the data that is going to be acted upon in the test, the *Act*-portion of a Unit Test is usually one line. It activates the portion of code being tested, passing in that data. Finally, the *Assert* portion of the test takes the *Act* portion results and verifies that it met expectations (can be zero lines when just making sure there is no error).

Unit Test generators generally can only do the *Arrange*, and *Act* portions on unit test creation; however, unit test generators generally do not write *Assert* portions as only you know what is correct and what is incorrect for your purposes. So some manual entry/extending of Unit Tests is necessary for completeness.

Comment: Oh and Pex, is now Intellitest [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823749.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon. Certain types of testing, like automated fuzz testing, definitely benefit from automated generation. While you can use the facilities of a unit testing framework to accomplish this, this doesn't accomplish the goals associated with good unit test coverage.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [NStub](http://code.google.com/p/nstub/) to stub out test for my classes. It works fairly well.

Comment: There's a newer repo on GitHub @ https://github.com/Jedzia/NStub which may be more useful ... or not.

Answer (score -1):

There is a commercial product called AgitarOne (www.agitar.com) that automatically generates JUnit test classes.
I haven't used it so can't comment on how useful it is, but if I was doing a Java project at the moment I would be looking at it.

I don't know of a .net equivalent (Agitar did one announce a .net version but AFAIK it never materialised).

Answer (score -2):

I've used tools to generate test cases.  I think it works well for higher-level, end-user oriented testing.  Stuff that's part of User Acceptance Testing, more so than pure unit testing.

I use the unit test tools for this acceptance testing.  It works well.

See [Tooling to Build Test Cases](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/iblog/architecture/C20071019092637/E20080830091128/index.html).

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"503 Service Unavailable"*.

Answer (score -4):

I know this thread is old but for the sake of all developpers, there is a good library called nunit :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.TestGeneratorNUnitextension

EDIT :
Please use XUNIT ( Supported by microsoft ) : https://github.com/xunit/xunit

Autogenerated test  :
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YowkoTsai.xUnitnetTestGenerator

Good dev

Comment: and these days it doesn't exist anymore... link only answers...

Answer (score -6):

[Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) generates unit tests from user commands on a web page, pretty nifty.

Comment: Selenium generates functional tests rather than unit tests.

Functional testing accesses the application as a user would. Unit tests access it under the hood.