# Good tools which generate NUnit unit tests for .NET assemblies in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit, code-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Auto-generation of .NET unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142481/auto-generation-of-net-unit-tests)

I am pretty new to Unit Testing so bear with me.

I realize that best best practice is not to auto generate unit tests, however I'd like to use Code Generation to set-up the basic skeleton of the tests.

Now, I know Visual Studio 2008 already has the built in "create tests", however, it just creates a flat list of all the classes it's going to test... and it's not for NUnit right?

Ideally, I'd like the code generation to follow the folder AND namespace structure of the assembly its generating tests for.

Can you recommend any good tools which generate NUnit unit tests for .NET assemblies in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: I  think you mean "bear with me" because that means to go the same direction or handle the load, as opposed to disrobing which would seem to be what "bare with me" would mean.

Comment: oh. I definitely do not mean "bare with me"! cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/Pex), although it's beta and has a steep learning curve. [This article](http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/7963) might help.

Comment: cool, having a look now... but is it just VS2010?

Comment: I'm using it from VS2008

Comment: Thanks HeavyWave, been looking at Pex, looks great

Comment: Pex is not free, you have to be an MSDN subscriber to use it legally.

Answer (score 7):

There is quite a list:

1. [NStub](http://code.google.com/p/nstub/)
2. [TestGen.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/testgennet/)
3. [NunitGenAddIn](http://code.google.com/p/nunitgenaddin/)
4. ($$)[KellerMan NUnit Test Generator](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-30-nunit-test-generator.aspx?mode=Specifications&)
5. [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)
6. [MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182524%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) - fair enough this is not NUnit, but it does generate tests and should be "considered"