# Create test classes automatically

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

We are working on a VS solution for CRM Dynamics. There are a few projects in the solution for Plugins/workflows. Also a Test project for unit tests. 
The objective is to automatically create a test class in Test project for each class file created in the other projects. Say, creating UpdateAccount2.cs in UpdateAccount2 should create Test_Plugin_UpdateAccount2.cs in CRM_Unit_Tests project.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-generation of .NET unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142481/auto-generation-of-net-unit-tests)

Comment: This is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142481/auto-generation-of-net-unit-tests. There is really nothing specific to Dynamics CRM in regard to auto-generating unit tests in .NET, anymore than there would be hitting a SQL DB, etc.